# Variable Properties in JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have the following example JSON, for which I want to write a JSON Schema. The constraint is that property2 holds a list of string, which are dynamic, depending on the dataset. And in the property3 object some of the properties are named afters those strings.

```
 {
   "property1": "value",
   "property2": ["value1","value2","value2"],
   "property3": {
                   "title": "test",
                   "value1": "hello",
                   "value2": "world"
    }
 }
```

A JSON-Schema might look like this, but I don't know how to describe that the dynamic properties. Is that possible?

```
 {
   "title": "Test Object",
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
              "property1": {
                     "type": "string"
               }
              "property1": {
                     "type": "array"
               }
              "property3": {
                     "type": "object",
                     "properties": {
                               "title": {
                                     "type": "string"
                               }
                               [ Something is missing here ]
                      }
               }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not relate property values to property keys with Json-Schema (as of Draft v4).

You can:

- Define property2 as an schema and reference it (#ref) from property3 (dependencies,allOf, anyOf, additionalProperties...). If these property names are very dynamic in your case you might build this schema on the fly.
- Use patternProperties in order to retrict valid property names in property3 to some fixed regex.